# Wrong intrinsicContentSize (width) of UITextField using monospacedDigitSystemFont causing clipped text

Tags: ios, fonts, autolayout, uitextfield

I have a UITextField that contains text with numbers, and I have a terrible time trying to use auto-layout with that view. Depending on the numbers, it will sometimes be too narrow so all the text does not show. This happens only when I use monospacedDigitSystemFont. Furthermore, it does not happen if I use a UILabel rather than a UITextField. It happens when there are several “narrow” digits (such as 1) in the text, not when the digits are all “wide” (such as 5). It seems that the UITextField calculates its `intrinsicContentSize` without rendering the digits monospaced. How to fix this?

This graphic illustrates the problem. The orange background shows UILabel, while yellow background shows UITextField. The problem is seen only in the top yellow box (which has narrow digits “111111”).

[image: Yellow for UITextField, orange for UILabel]

I have a work-around: use the attributedString property instead of assigning the font directly to the UITextField, however I'm hoping someone has a better solution. The playground code for the graphic is here:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

func place(subview:UIView, on view:UIView, x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat) {
    view.addSubview(subview)
    subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: x).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: y).isActive = true
    subview.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
}

let numericFont = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .regular)

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 170))
containerView.backgroundColor = .lightGray

let textWithNarrowDigits = "111111 narrow digits"
let textWithWideDigits = "555555 wide digits"

func show(text:String, topOffset:CGFloat) {
    // Using UILabel - works as expected
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = numericFont
    label.text = text
    label.backgroundColor = .orange
    print("Label intrinsicContentSize:\(label.intrinsicContentSize)") // width = 177 for narrow digits
    place(subview: label, on:containerView, x: 20, y: topOffset)

    // Using UITextField - width is too small (as if not monospaced)
    let field = UITextField()
    field.font = numericFont
    field.text = text
    field.backgroundColor = .yellow
    print("Field intrinsicContentSize:\(field.intrinsicContentSize)") // width = 161  for narrow digits
    place(subview: field, on:containerView, x: 20, y: topOffset + 30)

}

show(text: textWithNarrowDigits, topOffset: 10)
show(text: textWithWideDigits, topOffset: 100)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my workaround. Instead of:

```
field.font = numericFont
field.text = text
```

use:

```
field.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : numericFont])
```

Doing this, the UITextField seems to calculate its intrinsicContentSize correctly even with the monospaced narrow digits. But I’m still hoping for a real solution.